# Approach to speed up pandas multilevel index selection?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a data frame, and would like to work on a small partition each time for particular  tuples of values of `'a', 'b','c'`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(0,10,10000),
                   'b':np.random.randint(0,10,10000),
                   'c':np.random.randint(0,10,10000),
                   'value':np.random.randint(0,100,10000)})
```

so I chose to use pandas multiindex:

```
dfi = df.set_index(['a','b','c'])
dfi.sortlevel(inplace = True)
```

However, the performance is not great.

```
%timeit dfi.ix[(2,1,7)] # 511 us
%timeit df[(df['a'].values == 2) & 
           (df['b'].values == 1) & (df['c'].values == 7)] # 247 us
```

I suspect there are some overheads somewhere. My program has ~1k tuples, so it takes 511 * 1000 = 0.5s for one run. How can I improve further?

#### update:

hmm, I forgot to mention that the number of tuples are less than the total Cartesian product of distinct values in `'a', 'b','c'` in df. Wouldn't `groupby` do excess amount of work on indices that doesn't exist in my tuples?

Comment: What operation are you doing with each tuple? Can you vectorize so that you do it over all tuples simultaneously and then just need to index the results?

Comment: @colinfang the cartesian product is not an issue here, only the actual number of groups. If you only want to operate on way less than the total number of groups (say a handful), then direct indexing will win, otherwise groupby will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
dfi = df.set_index(['a','b','c'])
dfi.sortlevel(inplace = True)
value = dfi["value"].values
value[dfi.index.get_loc((2, 1, 7))]
```

the result is a ndarray without index.

Answer (score 4):

its not clear what 'work' on means, but I would do this

this can be almost any function

```
In [33]: %timeit df.groupby(['a','b','c']).apply(lambda x: x.sum())
10 loops, best of 3: 83.6 ms per loop
```

certain operations are cythonized so very fast

```
In [34]: %timeit df.groupby(['a','b','c']).sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.65 ms per loop
```

Doing a a selection on a multi-index is not efficient to do index by index.

If you are operating on a very small subset of the total groups, then you might want to directly index into the multi-index; groupby wins if you are operating on a fraction (maybe 20%) of the groups or more. You might also want to investigate `filter` which you can use to pre-filter the groups based on some criteria.

As noted above, the cartesian product of the groups indexers is irrelevant. Only the actual groups will be iterated by groupby (think of a MultiIndex as a sparse representation of the total possible space).

Comment: Does pandas have `groupby after join` similar functional? So I can right join the df with my list of tuple (on the multi index) and then `groupby`?